# Python - Parse through Dictionary with List

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am using python to try and parse through this value.

```
[{'value': {'stringValue': 'My Name'}, 'label': "Submitter's Name", 'type': 'string'}, {'value': {'stringValue': 'Shipper name test'}, 'label': 'Shipper Name', 'type': 'string'}, {'value': {'stringValue': 'Consignee name test'}, 'label': 'Consignee', 'type': 'string'}, {'value': {'stringValue': '12345'}, 'label': 'Job #', 'type': 'string'}, {'value': {'numberValue': 67}, 'label': 'Temp', 'type': 'number'}, {'value': {'multipleChoiceValue': [{'selected': True, 'value': 'YES'}, {'selected': False, 'value': 'NO'}]}, 'label': 'Visual Inspection', 'type': 'multipleChoice'}, {'value': {'multipleChoiceValue': [{'selected': True, 'value': 'YES'}, {'selected': False, 'value': 'NO'}]}, 'label': 'Water', 'type': 'multipleChoice'}, {'value': {'multipleChoiceValue': [{'selected': True, 'value': 'YES'}, {'selected': False, 'value': 'NO'}]}, 'label': 'Feed', 'type': 'multipleChoice'}, {'value': {'multipleChoiceValue': [{'selected': True, 'value': 'YES'}, {'selected': False, 'value': 'NO'}]}, 'label': 'Lights', 'type': 'multipleChoice'}, {'value': {'multipleChoiceValue': [{'selected': True, 'value': 'YES'}, {'selected': False, 'value': 'NO'}, {'selected': False, 'value': 'Yes, but needs attention'}]}, 'label': 'Bed', 'type': 'multipleChoice'}, {'value': {'multipleChoiceValue': [{'selected': True, 'value': 'Vehicle 1'}, {'selected': False, 'value': 'Vehicle 3'}, {'selected': False, 'value': 'Vehicle 3'}, {'selected': False, 'value': 'Vehicle 4'}]}, 'label': 'Truck#', 'type': 'multipleChoice'}, {'value': {}, 'label': 'Room#', 'type': 'multipleChoice'}, {'value': {'multipleChoiceValue': [{'selected': True, 'value': 'NO'}, {'selected': False, 'value': 'YES'}]}, 'label': 'Last Submission for Trip?', 'type': 'multipleChoice'}]
```

Below I run into an error at the for loop:  `for choice2 in fields2['value']['multipleChoiceValue']: KeyError: 'multipleChoiceValue'`

```
for fields in response_data['data']['fields']:
    if fields['label'] == "Last Submission for Trip?":
        for choice in fields['value']['multipleChoiceValue']:
            if choice['value'] == "NO":
                if choice['selected'] == True:
                    for fields2 in response_data['data']['fields']:
                        if fields2['type'] == 'multipleChoice':
                           for choice2 in fields2['value']['multipleChoiceValue']:
                              print('selected')
                              print('value')
```

I can see the `type` and `label` no problem with the IF statement.  But I can't seem to understand how to unwrap the list so I can cycle through the two dicts that are available to me.

**UPDATE:**
I found the solution.  Thank you @Stark for simplifying it for me to visually see it.

my payload had an empty value - `{'value': {}, 'label': 'Room#', 'type': 'multipleChoice'}`

I simply added an `and` operator to my if statement before the for loop:
`if fields2['type'] == 'multipleChoice' and fields2['value'] != {}:`

Comment: This is not a valid Python data structure you posted. Is there maybe another object in your data that has type multipleChoice, but is missing the mCV key?

Comment: After fixed `true` and `false` to `True` and `False` respectively, I can run the snippet you shared. Help us help you - olease share a [mcve]

Comment: updated with the full payload and the full program up to the last for loop.

Comment: Would it have to do with the empty dict?  {'value': {}, 'label': 'Room#', 'type': 'multipleChoice'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, it works for me,
I have used True and False instead of true and false because that is an undefined keyword which you are using.

```
fields2={
    "value":{
            "multipleChoiceValue":[
                {
                "selected":True,
                "value":"YES"
                },
                {
                "selected":False,
                "value":"NO"
                }
            ]
        },
        "label":"Visual Inspection",
        "type":"multipleChoice"
}
if fields2['type'] == 'multipleChoice':
    for choice2 in fields2['value']['multipleChoiceValue']:
        print(choice2)
```

Comment: This isn't a payload I can change.  It's from a Rest API.

Comment: Looking at the payload I am getting it's already True and False like you show above.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: The payload I have looks like this at this stage in the program:  {'value': {'multipleChoiceValue': [{'selected': True, 'value': 'YES'}, {'selected': False, 'value': 'NO'}]}, 'label': 'Visual Inspection', 'type': 'multipleChoice'}

Comment: one of the entries got a blank value field, thats the reason,
ps: i saw the update too in your question, good to know that it works now.